# error while executing test with soapui-maven plugin 5.4.0

Tags: maven, soapui

I am executing my SOAPUI project with maven and getting following error. How can I find out which class is missing as error mentions that A required class is missing but not the name of the class? Below out is after executing `mvn -e`

```
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test (ServiceCPEWebservice-soapui-project.
    xml) on project Single_Service: Execution ServiceCPEWebservice-soapui-project.xml of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-ma
    ven-plugin:5.4.0:test failed: A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.
    0:test: org/apache/log4j/Layout**
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.4.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.4.0.j
    ar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/5.4.0/soapui-5.4.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
    [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] : org.apache.log4j.Layout
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:
    5.4.0:test (ServiceCPEWebservice-soapui-project.xml) on project Single_Service: Execution ServiceCPEWebservice-soapui-pr
    oject.xml of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test failed: A required class was missing while executi
    ng com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test: org/apache/log4j/Layout
    -----------------------------------------------------
    realm =    plugin>com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0
    strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    urls[0] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.4.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.4.0.jar
    urls[1] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/5.4.0/soapui-5.4.0.jar
    urls[2] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
    Number of foreign imports: 1
    import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

    -----------------------------------------------------

            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.
    java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution ServiceCPEWebservice-soapui-project.xml of goal c
    om.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test failed: A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear.so
    apui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test: org/apache/log4j/Layout
    -----------------------------------------------------
    realm =    plugin>com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0
    strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    urls[0] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.4.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.4.0.jar
    urls[1] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/5.4.0/soapui-5.4.0.jar
    urls[2] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
    Number of foreign imports: 1
    import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

    -----------------------------------------------------

            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear.
    soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test: org/apache/log4j/Layout
    -----------------------------------------------------
    realm =    plugin>com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0
    strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    urls[0] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.4.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.4.0.jar
    urls[1] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/5.4.0/soapui-5.4.0.jar
    urls[2] = file:/C:/work/m2-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
    Number of foreign imports: 1
    import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

    -----------------------------------------------------

            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
            ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
            at com.eviware.soapui.maven2.TestMojo.execute(TestMojo.java:52)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
            ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
            ... 23 more
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :Single_Service
```

I have two poms. 1 is master POM and 1 is child POM.

Below are the POMs

**Master POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.orange.papyrus.customercare</groupId>
    <artifactId>FullRegression</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
                <modules>
                <module>AutomationSingleTest</module>
                <module>AutomationCompleteTest</module>
                </modules>
                <properties>
            <soap.path>${project.basedir}/../North/CC_Projects</soap.path>
            <soap.version>5.4.0</soap.version>
            <soap.outputFolder>${project.build.directory}</soap.outputFolder>
            <soap.ip>${ipaddress}</soap.ip>
            <soap.port>${port}</soap.port>
            <soap.username>${username}</soap.username>
            <soap.password>${password}</soap.password>
            <soap.servicename>${servicename}</soap.servicename>
            <soap.serviceendpoint>${endpoint}</soap.serviceendpoint>
        </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>        
        <configuration>
            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
        <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports/</outputFolder>
        <printReport>true</printReport>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4</version>
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>

 </build>
</project>
```

**Child POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <parent>
     <groupId>com.orange.papyrus.customercare</groupId>
     <artifactId>FullRegression</artifactId>
     <version>10.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </parent>  
        <artifactId>Single_Service</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                     <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>${servicename}</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                   <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
                 <configuration>
                   <projectFile>${soap.path}/${servicename}</projectFile>
                   <endpoint>http://${soap.ip}:${soap.port}/${soap.serviceendpoint}</endpoint>
                   <username>${soap.username}</username>
                   <password>${soap.password}</password>
                 </configuration>
               </execution>
             </executions>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout"

Comment: thanks Steen .got the error but havn't found the solution yet I have checked the code if We are using the log4j somewhere but havenot found. can Any body help me with solution

Answer (score 1):

I think the version of `maven-surefire-report-plugin`, you are using `3.5.4` is not published yet. The latest version is `3.0.0-M3`
[Maven Surefire Report Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin)

Update the *Maven Surefire Report Plugin* version, which exists.

Though the error is coming from log4j library. Do you have any custom configuration to generate log? Then the layout is not properly written. 
Check here the custome SOAPUI [soapui-log4j.xml](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/41542c897f44a84543f97dcc3de4f3595c359d65/soapui-system-test/src/test/resources/config/soapui-test-log4j.xml) file

One of my [API Testing](https://github.com/royki/QAFramework/blob/apiAdidas/apiAdidas/pom.xml) using maven with SOAPUI. Check this and try to modify in your `Master` pom file. Hope that would solve your problem.